# Problem with running UI tests in xcode 14

Tags: swift, xcode, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

I cleaned Derived Data for my simulator where I ran ui tests, after that I got compilation error:

> Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/somename/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project-hcpgozxlrdkdmzdzditvdlebgrva/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ProjectUITests-Runner.app/PlugIns/ProjectUITests.xctest/ProjectUITests'. Did you forget to declare this file as an output of a script phase or custom build rule which produces it?

This error spears if you press "Command + U", the button to start individual autotests (to the right of the test) has disappeared:

[image]

1. I rebooted xcode
2. I rebooted my macbook
3. I checked the file at the above path, there really is no ProjectUITests file into

   ProjectUITests.xctest:

> ➜  ProjectUITests.xctest ls -al
>
> drwxr-xr-x  15 ivnikiforo  1402375171     480 26 мар 10:27 .
>
> drwxr-xr-x   3 ivnikiforo  1402375171      96 26 мар 10:24 ..
>
> drwxr-xr-x  37 ivnikiforo  1402375171    1184 26 мар 10:27 Frameworks
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 ivnikiforo  1402375171     773 26 мар 10:27 Info.plist
>
> drwxr-xr-x   4 ivnikiforo  1402375171     128 26 мар 08:45 TagManagerResources.bundle
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 ivnikiforo  1402375171     192 26 мар 10:27 V3LoginRoute.json
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 ivnikiforo  1402375171    3440 26 мар 10:27 VSPV3Authenticate.json
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 ivnikiforo  1402375171   33522 26 мар 10:27 VSPV3Login.json
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 ivnikiforo  1402375171     875 26 мар 10:27 VSPV3OnLineHeartbeat.json
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 ivnikiforo  1402375171     897 26 мар 10:27 VSPV3PlayVOD.json
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 ivnikiforo  1402375171  175710 26 мар 10:27 VSPV3QueryCustomizeConfig.json
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 ivnikiforo  1402375171  116410 26 мар 10:27 VSPV3QueryPlaybillListStcPropsMainPage.json
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 ivnikiforo  1402375171    1182 26 мар 10:27 VSPV3QuerySubscriber.json
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 ivnikiforo  1402375171     273 26 мар 10:27 VSPV3SetGlobalFilterCond.json
>
> -rw-r--r--   1 ivnikiforo  1402375171  381842 26 мар 10:27 pagesMAIN.json

In xcode, these files are visible in the UI test target

[image]

4. I checked UITest is enabled into scheme.

5. UItest target has next In pods

[image]

I also noticed, that in build phases of UItest target don't have build phase with compile sources.

I have no idea why the test files have become unavailable for tests launch and where to fix the path or settings so that everything works? I think cleaning delivered data is a common thing to automatically run tests on CI and this shouldn't affect the launch of autotests.

I will be glad of any help.

Comment: Typically when the individual button for running a test disappears, it's because you've made some mistake in your test file. The mistake that I tend to make is that due to copy and paste I end up with two methods with the same name. This upsets Xcode even if I then change the name, as one must in order to compile the tests, and I end up having to delete the DerivedData. Please note that you must _quit_ Xcode completely before deleting DerivedData, and it is a good idea then to restart the whole darned computer, believe it or not.

Comment: If that doesn't help, maybe something has gone wrong with the project; it seems like your UI tests might not be tests at all. You might have to create a new UI test target and move your files into it.

Comment: Something went wrong with the project, after the test target was recreated, the tests started working.

Comment: Excellent! Glad you got it fixed.

Comment: Since the problem is solved you really should delete the question. Don't leave it hanging.